# Serializing JPA Entity - saving only IDs for fetched entities

Tags: java, jpa, serialization, jaxb

There are two entities: User and Employee. User has field with type Employee.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User extends AuditableEntity {    
    Long idUser;
    String username;
    String password;
    Employee employee;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getIdUser() { return idUser; }  
    public void setIdUser(Long idUser) { this.idUser = idUser; }

    @Column(name = "username")
    public String getUsername() { return username; }
    public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }

    @Column(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() { return password; }
    public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idemployee")    
    public Employee getEmployee() { return employee; }
    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) { this.employee = employee; }
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee extends AuditableEntity { 
    Long        idEmployee;
    String      surname;
    String      name;
    String      patronymic;
    Date        birthdate;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idemployee")
    public Long getIdEmployee() { return idEmployee; }
    public void setIdEmployee(Long idEmployee) { this.idEmployee = idEmployee; }

    @Column(name = "surname")
    public String getSurname() { return surname; }
    public void setSurname(String surname) { this.surname = surname; }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    @Column(name = "patronymic")
    public String getPatronymic() { return patronymic; }
    public void setPatronymic(String patronymic) { this.patronymic = patronymic; }

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
    @Column(name = "birthday")
    public Date getBirthdate() { return birthdate; }
    public void setBirthdate(Date birthdate) { this.birthdate = birthdate; }
}
```

I need to serialize User to XML/JSON. I'm using JAXB but it's serializing Employee too:

```
<User>
    <idUser>15</idUser>
    <username>user15</username>
    <password>password15</password>
    <employee>
        <idEmployee>23</idEmployee>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
        <name>John</name>
        <patronymic>H.</patronymic>
        <birthdate>01.01.1970</birthdate>
    </employee>
<User>
```

I need in result something like this:

```
<User>
    <idUser>15</idUser>
    <username>user15</username>
    <password>password15</password>   
    <idEmployee>23</idEmployee>    
<User>
```

I tried to use @XmlID, @XmlIDREF - but it's usable only with String id column.
Also tried to use @XmlTransient - but it's only excluding Employee.
How i can serialize User without Employee, only with idEmployee?

And second question is deserialization. Are there any standard ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Annotate property `employee` in class `User` with `@XmlTransient`. This annotation can be applied to either field or its getter.

Comment: This is excluding entire field. But I need to save the employee's ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional getter for Employee's id to `User` entity

```
public class User
{   
    ...  
    @Transient // for JPA
    @XmlElement 
    Long getIdEmployee()
    {
       return employee.getIdEmployee();
    }
}
```

Or you can do it with `@XmlValue`

```
public class User
{  
    ...  
    @XmlElement(name = "idEmployee")
    public Employee getEmployee() { return employee; }
    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) { this.employee = employee; }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) // to prevent marshalling of all properies
public class Employee 
{ 
   ...
   @XmlValue
   public Long getIdEmployee() { return idEmployee; }
   ...
}
```